# Is it possible to do simple decryption in a web browser using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, encryption, browser

As part of a small neighborhood scavenger hunt game I want to make some very simple html tables and hyperlinks available via the internet but I want to make sure the data isn’t viewable until a password is entered. The password isn’t for security but rather as a fun way to let the person know whether they have an answer to a question correct (The site won’t decrypt unless they answered a question correctly) At the same time I don’t want some clever kid to just view the page source and see the password in plane text somewhere in the page. 
My idea is for the html file to contain a “blob” of previously encrypted data and some unencrypted JavaScript which can decode the encrypted blob when the correct “password” is entered. I want all the decryption to occur in the browser and the webserver will have no idea whether or not the correct password is entered. Is this even possible? If so, can someone give a high level process or point me to an example of how to do this? What JavaScript libraries should I use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the code in the page can decrypt something, then anybody who's loaded the page into a browser can decrypt it too. There's really no such thing as "simple" security if you care at all whether it works.

Comment: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha256.html

Comment: Anything you do on the client is visible to any 'clever kid' who has a mind to look. Given that libraries like jQuery make AJAX very simple, why not do this on the server?

Comment: @HoboSapiens and Pointy : Thanks so much for the comments, but isn't there a way to encrypt something so that it can't be decrypted without the proper key?Even if someone had all the code and the encrypted blob, they still don't have the "key" which was originally used to encrypt. The only way they could decrypt the text would be a dictionary or brute force attack, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do decryption in a browser.  There are javascript libraries that can be used that will implement common crypto algorithms.

The challenge in a client-only encryption operation is that nothing in your Javascript code is a secret.  Everything is known and available to anyone who wants to look.  So, you can't securely store an encryption or decryption key in your Javascript.  Without a secure key, all you'd really have is obscuration which is not to be confused with security.  Obscuration just makes the code harder to read, but any determined hacker will eventually be able to figure out the content (it is not cryptographically secure).

Sometimes, obscuration can meet your needs by just raising the snooping bar high enough that it won't be worth the effort.  But, it is very, very important to realize that obscuration is not real security.  It's kind of like building the fence just a little higher, but the front door is still not locked.  Any determined person will just climb over the higher fence and then they can walk right in the front door.

Without a doubt, the usual way to solve this is to involve a server in the operation and have the server check credentials and only offer questions or answers when the client has met the necessary conditions.  Since the server can have secure storage, it can store answers or passwords or any other secrets and only reveal new content when appropriate conditions have been met by the client.